# Target checked checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML, CSS and jQuery code for a checkbox. But I was recently making some changes in the HTML structure and now the jQuery is no longer working. And since I'm a beginner, I don't know how to fix this.

Can someone take a look and just let me know what jQuery should be targeting instead, so it'll change the styling of the elements when the checkbox is checked?

```js
$('.form-check').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.incomplete').css('display', (this.checked)?'none':'block')
        $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.complete').css('display', (this.checked)?'block':'none')
        $(this).closest('.list-group-item').css('background-color',(this.checked)?'#4CAF50':'')
        $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.custom-control-description').css('color', (this.checked)?'#fff':'#2c2b2c')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.custom-control-description').css('text-decoration-color', (this.checked)?'#fff':'#ababab')
})
```

```css
.custom-control-box {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #1b7e45;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #1b7e45;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
  border: 1px solid #4c4c4d;
}
.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #1b7e45;
  }
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + svg {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + svg {
  display: block;
}
.form-check {
  position: relative;
}
.form-check label {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-control-description {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.6;
} 

.form-check label svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<li class="list-group-item p-4 border-top-0  first-group-item">
  <div class="form-check mb-0">
    <label class="mb-0">
      <span class="custom-control-box align-middle"></span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item_1" value="item 1" id="checkbox"/>
      <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
      <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
      <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
      </svg>
      <span class="custom-control-description align-middle">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
</div> <!-- /.form-check -->
<div class="ml-auto status">
  <p class="mb-0 incomplete">pending</p>
  <p class="mb-0 complete">done</p>
</div>
</li>
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working? Does it not run at all? Does it run but not performing the expected behavior? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @FreemanLambda It doesn't style the elements when the checkbox is checked. But it did work before my HTML update. So I'm assuming it's because I'm targeting the wrong thing in the jQuery. But I have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `this.isChecked`, it is always undefined, so it always evaluates to false. I replaced it with `isChecked`, getting the value from the `checked` property of the checkbox belonging to this li item.

```js
$('.form-check').click(function(){
  var isChecked = $(this).find('#checkbox').prop('checked');
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.incomplete').css('display', isChecked?'none':'block')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.complete').css('display', isChecked?'block':'none')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').css('background-color',isChecked?'#4CAF50':'')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.custom-control-description').css('color', isChecked?'#fff':'#2c2b2c')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.custom-control-description').css('text-decoration-color', isChecked?'#fff':'#ababab')
})
```

```css
.custom-control-box {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #1b7e45;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}
.checkmark {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #1b7e45;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
  border: 1px solid #4c4c4d;
}
.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes scale {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #1b7e45;
  }
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + svg {
  display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + svg {
  display: block;
}
.form-check {
  position: relative;
}
.form-check label {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.custom-control-description {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.6;
} 

.form-check label svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<li class="list-group-item p-4 border-top-0  first-group-item">
  <div class="form-check mb-0">
    <label class="mb-0">
      <span class="custom-control-box align-middle"></span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item_1" value="item 1" id="checkbox"/>
      <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
      <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
      <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
      </svg>
      <span class="custom-control-description align-middle">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div> <!-- /.form-check -->
  <div class="ml-auto status">
    <p class="mb-0 incomplete">pending</p>
    <p class="mb-0 complete">done</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the `.form-check` if it is checked.. It should be the `checkbox` inside the `.form-check`.

Find the `checkbox` inside the `.form-check` first and the check for its `prop` if checked or not as follows:

```js
$('.form-check').click(function() {
  var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.incomplete').css('display', (checkbox.prop('checked')) ? 'none' : 'block')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.complete').css('display', (checkbox.prop('checked')) ? 'block' : 'none')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').css('background-color', (checkbox.prop('checked')) ? '#4CAF50' : '')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.custom-control-description').css('color', (checkbox.prop('checked')) ? '#fff' : '#2c2b2c')
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.custom-control-description').css('text-decoration-color', (checkbox.prop('checked')) ? '#fff' : '#ababab')
})
```

```css
.custom-control-box {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.checkmark__circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 166;
  stroke-dashoffset: 166;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  stroke: #1b7e45;
  animation: stroke 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) forwards;
}

.checkmark {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px #1b7e45;
  animation: fill .4s ease-in-out .4s forwards, scale .3s ease-in-out .9s both;
  border: 1px solid #4c4c4d;
}

.checkmark__check {
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  stroke-dasharray: 48;
  stroke-dashoffset: 48;
  animation: stroke 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.65, 0, 0.45, 1) 0.8s forwards;
}

@keyframes stroke {
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scale {
  0%,
  100% {
    transform: none;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale3d(1.1, 1.1, 1);
  }
}

@keyframes fill {
  100% {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 30px #1b7e45;
  }
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]+svg {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+svg {
  display: block;
}

.form-check {
  position: relative;
}

.form-check label {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-control-description {
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 2.6;
}

.form-check label svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<li class="list-group-item p-4 border-top-0  first-group-item">
  <div class="form-check mb-0">
    <label class="mb-0">
      <span class="custom-control-box align-middle"></span>
      <input type="checkbox" name="item_1" value="item 1" id="checkbox"/>
      <svg class="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 52 52">
      <circle class="checkmark__circle" cx="26" cy="26" r="25" fill="none" />
      <path class="checkmark__check" fill="none" d="M14.1 27.2l7.1 7.2 16.7-16.8" />
      </svg>
      <span class="custom-control-description align-middle">Checkbox</span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <!-- /.form-check -->
  <div class="ml-auto status">
    <p class="mb-0 incomplete">pending</p>
    <p class="mb-0 complete">done</p>
  </div>
</li>
```